# how to break a long string and display in text line

Tags: visualforce

How can a long text string break and display into next line.

i am rendering my visualforce page as a pdf format. in vf Page, i am showing 6 fields into table and if text field values are long text then it increase the column width.

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: Some code sample will be very helpful for us to understand your problem.